# How to find multiply elements with same path in one page using Selenium Xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I try to pull the 'Text I Want' data with selenium using python.

The code I used below only pull the first one.

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class = "sth3"]/span')
e.text
```

What should I do?
The page source below:

```
<li id = "12345" class = "sth">
 <div class = "sth1">
  <div class = "sth2">
   <a>
    <div class = "sth3">
     <span class = "sth4">Text I Want</span>
<li id = "12345" class = "sth">
 <div class = "sth1">
  <div class = "sth2">
   <a>
    <div class = "sth3">
     <span class = "sth4">Text I Want</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
text_list = [e.text for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@class = "sth3"]/span')]
```

This should allow you to get list of text contents from all required elements

Answer (score -1):

```
// First find out the elements having xpath span and store it in the list of elements.  
  List<WebElements> list_ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span"));

then with the help of for loop print value of each span text.

    for(webElement x : list){
        system.out.println(x.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].